# C OpenMP - Enforce default chunk size

Tags: c, scheduling, openmp

In C to parallelize a loop with `schedule(static)` would mean that the chunk size is quickly computed as **`ceil`**`(loops/threads)`.

For my project I have to iterrate through 9 different chunk sizes, one of which is "default". This is how I did it:

I wrote a perl loop that compiles my program with `-DCHUNKSIZE=$c` and in the `omp` code I specify `schedule(static, CHUNKSIZE)`.

**Question**: what can I do for default? Chunk size of 0 doesn't work :(

Thanks!

P.S.
I was hoping to avoid having `#ifdef ... #else ... #endif` since I have very many loops that are parallelized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with ejd. As to how to handle it, why not:

```
#ifdef CHUNKSIZE
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(mode, CHUNKSIZE)
#else
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(mode)
#endif
for ( ; ; ) /* ... */
```

and then not pass `-DCHUNKSIZE` for the default.

Comment: Forgot to mention... I have like 20 loops, and was hoping to avoid having ifdef/else/endif everywhere

Comment: @Mikhail Ahhh. I want to say the default is 1, but I don't know whether or not it is guaranteed to be, I'll have to have a look.

Comment: it's not 1, it actually computes the number of loops and breaks it into the number of threads

Answer (score 1):

You have to leave the chunksize off completely and just specify "schedule(kind)".

Comment: Are you saying it's not possible to automate default chunk size and particular ones?

Comment: The problem is, that there is no way to specify to use the default chunksize except to leave it off.  Some implementations allow a chunksize=0 to mean use the default, but others will just set the value of chunksize to 1 if you do this.  The OpenMP specification doesn't allow for it.  User Ninefingers has shown an example of how you can do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
#ifdef CHUNKSIZE
#define OPM_FOR(mode) _Pragma("omp parallel for schedule(" #mode ", "CHUNKSIZE")")
#else
#define OMP_FOR(mode) _Pragma("omp parallel for schedule(" #mode ")")
#endif

OMP_FOR(static)
for ( ; ; ) { /* */ }
```

Basically, Æsahættr's solution with the additional use of the _Pragma() operator (which is in C99, I believe).